# Parsing an array of strings with JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON structure that looks like this, it's essentially a bash shell command stored in JSON. Is there a way in jq to map this data back to multiline string ?

```
[
  "newcert \\\n",
  "    --cn server1.acme.com \\\n",
  "    --san-dns server1.acme.com \\\n",
  "    --key-file ./config/key.pem \\\n",
  "    --csr-file ./config/csr.pem \\\n",
  "    --no-prompt \\\n"
]
```

I need to map it back to a string that looks like this:

```
  newcert \
      --cn server1.acme.com \
      --san-dns server1.acme.com \
      --key-file ./config/key.pem \
      --csr-file ./config/csr.pem \
      --no-prompt \
```

Comment: What does "map this data back to a command" mean?

Comment: Sorry should be clearer. I need to map it back to a multiline string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `add` on the array, use `-r` for raw output (i.e. no escapes):

```
jq -r 'add' file.json
```

Answer (score 2):

As the lines already contain their newline symbols, you could instruct jq to omit its owns by using the `-j` option:

```bash
jq -j '.[]' file.json
```

```
newcert \
    --cn server1.acme.com \
    --san-dns server1.acme.com \
    --key-file ./config/key.pem \
    --csr-file ./config/csr.pem \
    --no-prompt \
```

Answer (score 0):

`jq` has a  `join` function:

```bash
cmd=$(jq -r '. | join("")' data.json)

# To execute it
eval $cmd
```

Standard security warning about `eval`: they can execute any command, so make sure you trust the input source.

Comment: `eval "$cmd"`, not `eval $cmd`. The differences are subtle, but when they matter, they matter a lot.

Comment: As a concrete example, let's say `cmd='rm *.txt'`. If you `eval "$cmd"` it'll just delete files matching the glob no matter what the names are. If on the other hand you have a file named `$(rm -rf ~).txt` and you run `eval $cmd` without the quotes, you're about to have a Very Bad Day, because the glob runs **before** the results are concatenated together into a command to parse and run.